# application:didReceiveRemoteNotication:fetchCompletionHandler not invoked after reboot the phone

Tags: ios, background-task, remote-notifications

When i reboot my phone without opening my app, and send a remote notification with 'content-available' bit, my app is not launched or invoke the delegate. But I can get the notification alert. The app was even launched for scheduled background fetch! Once I started my app by tap icon, the delegate is invoked as expected even if my app is in background or killed(not force quit).

Am I misunderstanding Apple's doc of this method or I'm missing something in my implementation?

It's running on iOS 9.3.1.

> Use this method to process incoming remote notifications for your app.
>   Unlike the application:didReceiveRemoteNotification: method, which is
>   called only when your app is running in the foreground, the system
>   calls this method when your app is running in the foreground or
>   background. In addition, if you enabled the remote notifications
>   background mode, the system launches your app (or wakes it from the
>   suspended state) and puts it in the background state when a push
>   notification arrives. However, the system does not automatically
>   launch your app if the user has force-quit it. In that situation, the
>   user must relaunch your app or restart the device before the system
>   attempts to launch your app automatically again.

Comment: Hi, did you get any solution to this?